# SQL Query that can return intersecting data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql

I have a hard time finding a good question title - let me just show you what I have and what the desired outcome is. I hope this can be done in SQL (I have SQL Server 2008).

1) I have a table called `Contacts` and in that table I have fields like these:

```
FirstName, LastName, CompanyName
```

2) Some demo data:

```
FirstName LastName CompanyName
John      Smith    Smith Corp
Paul      Wade  
Marc      Andrews  Microsoft
Bill      Gates    Microsoft
Steve     Gibbs    Smith Corp
Diane     Rowe     ABC Inc.
```

3) I want to get an intersecting list of people and companies, but companies only **once**. This would look like this:

```
Name
ABC Inc.
Bill Gates
Diane Rowe
John Smith   
Marc Andrews
Microsoft
Smith Corp
Steve Gibbs
Paul Wade
```

Can I do this with SQL? How?

Answer (score 2):

You take all the person names, and then also add all the companies

```
SELECT CONCAT([First Name],' ',[Last Name]) AS Name FROM Contacts
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT CompanyName FROM Contacts
   WHERE CompanyName IS NOT NULL
```

The DISTINCT keyword ensures that companies are output only once, and the WHERE
clause removes rows where no company info is known.

If a person has the same name as a company, then this will output a duplicate. If you don't want that, then change `UNION ALL` to `UNION`, and any name will be output only once.

Comment: It's interesting to see everybody's nuanced take on the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "intersecting," but you can easily get the results you describe as the union of two queries against that same table.

```
select
    t.firstname + ' ' + t.lastname
from
    mytable t
union
select
    t.company
from
    mytable t
```

Edit: UNION should make each SELECT distinct by default.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you need?

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS Name
FROM Contacts 
UNION
SELECT CompanyName
FROM Contacts
```

(The `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL` will ensure distinctness of both top and bottom parts. mdma's answer will work if you do need the possibility of duplicate people names. You might need to add an `ORDER BY Name` depending on your needs)